# How to read custom properties during MSI patch?

Tags: windows-installer

We have a setup that creates a shortcut that points to a virtual directory specified by the user (stored in a property during installation), for example, http://localhost/mydir.

Now I am making a patch, however, the value of the virtual directory is unavailable and the shortcut becomes empty.
How do I deal with it? I can’t change the original setup now since it is already released.

Is there a way to read the property back during the patch?
How come MSI "Repair" was able to read that value?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't persist properties across installation transactions.  You have to save the property somewhere (like the registry) and then read it back in so that the property still has a value otherwise it'll be null.

The repair likely didn't reinstall the components that create the shortcut and vdir so it didn't get wiped.  The patch likely did a REINSTALL=ALL and REINSTALLMODE=vomus  so they did get reinstalled and hence wiped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I manually delete the shortcut and do a repair, Windows Installer is able to restore the shortcut. And when I looked at the log file from the repair, MSI somehow was able to retrieve the value of the virtual directory.

Comment: Hence why I said "likely".  I suggest you log the repair and patch to get more data.

Comment: Never mind. I was wrong about MSI being able to retrieve the value of the custom property. It was just using the default value of the property. Anyways, thank you Christopher.